# Automatic Validating Each word individually(js)

Tags: javascript, validation, textfield

Im trying to get JS to validate text while I type automatically, but it doesn't go very well cause my JS skills are really bad. I am able to edit but not to write whatsoever. Can anyone point me in the right direction, please!

Im looking to get this effect http://goo.gl/iJpaOf

```
<div class="Stil35">Ja hodam za divovima, ali oni se plase</div>
<div class="Stil35">
<div id="hn_1" style="display: none;"><a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="tt('sn_1', 'hn_1')">I walk with giants, but they are afraid
</a></div></div>
<form><input type="text" style="width:600px" name="germantext"></form><br><br>
```

In text field I'm gonna type a word, say "I" (and this get check with) automatically and give me green or red, depending either it's wrong or correct.
Then I continue to type "walk" and again I get green or read, and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost what you want:

```
document.getElementById('myinput').onkeyup = validate;

var mytext = document.getElementById('mytext');
var str = mytext.innerHTML;
var originalTextArray = str.split('');

function validate() {
  var inputValue = this.value;
  var valueArray =inputValue.split('');
  var myTextArray = Array();
  for(var i = 0; i < valueArray.length; i++) {
      var char = originalTextArray[i];
      if(valueArray[i] !== char) {
          myTextArray[i] = '<span class="error">' + char + '</span>';
      } else {
         myTextArray[i] = '<span class="success">' + char + '</span>'; 
      }
  }

  var rest = str.substr(myTextArray.length);
  mytext.innerHTML = myTextArray.join('').concat(rest);  
}
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r8c68/1/)